# iphone app rejection question

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

My iPhone app was rejected with the following note:

> The following non-public APIs are included in your application:
>   Spi Symbols
>   __memset_chk
>   __memmove_chk"

These symbols appear in a small number of apparently cocos2d related object files:

- `Grid.o`
- `Primitives.o`
- `TextureAtlas.o`

Curiously, this app had already been approved under the previous SDK, but under 3.2 it's being rejected, though that may have nothing to do with it.

I'm not at all sure how to resolve this and appreciate any help anyone can offer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If cocos2d is using non-public API, I would suggest you first check if there is a newer version available that fixes this issue.

If you are already using the latest version then you should file a bug report with the cocos2d project and hope for a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm using version 0.99.0 of cocos2d and the current version is 0.99.2.  I made a copy of the project and replaced my library with the new one, but with no change.  The symbols still appear.

Comment: Not sure if I'm ready to report it as a bug but I am going to raise the question on the cocos2d-iphone forum.  Thanks again.

Comment: Bringing the issue to the attention of the developers is a good start.  At least they will become aware of the issue and hopefully plug the hole.

Comment: Your first instinct was correct.  I was wrong about what version I was using -- way wrong.  I don't know how I could have gotten it so mixed up, but I've now got my project running with the current version and that problem appears resolved.